# Butterfly Labs ASIC for rendering in 3dsmax

Tags: asic, butterfly-labs

Sorry if my question could be silly, but is there any option to perform 3d rendering on my Butterfly Labs ASICS?

As for now, I don't see any reason to farm bitcons on my 5Ghash ASICs, so I came up to an idea of making a rendering farm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of the problems with Bitcoin mining hardware, it cannot be repurposed to do anything else. It's not like a GPU where you can just use it to render graphics in a game.

ASICs are Application Specific Integrated Circuits. The "Application Specific" part is the key word here, they are specific to being used for mining only.